# drop down menu Sub-menu doesn't show

Tags: html, css, menu

I can't get the sub-menu to show when I hover a list item. What did I do wrong ?

It hides properly using display:none,  but doesnt show up when I hover.

```
nav ul ul {display: none;}

nav ul li:hover > ul{display: block;}
```

Complete code:

```
<nav>
        <ul>

        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
                </ul>

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
/* start NAVBAR */
nav ul,li{
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;  
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;  
  justify-content: center;

  list-style: none;
}

nav ul ul {display: none;}

nav ul li:hover > ul{display: block;}

nav ul {position: relative;}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

nav ul li a{
  color: black;
  #background-color: pink;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

nav ul li:hover{
  background-color: orange;
}

nav ul li ul {position: absolute; top:30px; left:0px;}

/* end NAVBAR */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you've closed your `li` element before you put the submenu in it. Move your closing `</li>` tag to after the `ul` submenu:

```
<li><a href="#">link2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Why? Because your CSS selection of `nav ul li:hover > ul{display: block;}` is expecting the `ul` element (that you want to show on hover) to be a **direct child** of the `li` element. In reality, your `ul` is not a child **at all**.